Cannot reference as foreign key because of missing data type
The RequestID has no data type so I can't make it as a foreign key in another table.
I encountered an error because I make RequestID as nvarchar(50) in another table but actually it don't have data type in origin table.
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestList]
(   
[Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,    
[RequestID]  AS  ('R'+right('000'+CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[Id]),(3))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
Date date,  
CustomerID nvarchar(50) foreign key references CustomerList(CustomerID),    
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RequestID] ASC),
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceList]
(   
ServiceID nvarchar(50) primary key, 
ServiceType nvarchar(50),   
Quantity int,   
UnitPrice decimal(10,2),    
TotalPrice decimal(10,2),   
[RequestID] nvarchar(50) foreign key references RequestList([RequestID]) NULL
)

Error because [dbo].[RequestList].[RequestID] have no data type, but I set it as nvarchar(50) in [dbo].[ServiceList]

Msg 1753, Level 16, State 1, Server a6e24afd5736, Line 2
Column 'RequestList.RequestID' is not the same length or scale as referencing column 'ServiceList.RequestID' in foreign key 'FK__ServiceLi__Reque__398D8EEE'. Columns participating in a foreign key relationship must be defined with the same length and scale.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Server a6e24afd5736, Line 2
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.


Based on the sql syntax I've replaced the MySql tag with the Sql-Server tag.

Please post the full, exact error

The error tells your precisely what the error is and how to fix it.

The datatype of a computed column is determined by SQL Server based on the expression used to create it. From official documentation:

The Database Engine determines the data type of the computed column by applying the rules of data type precedence to the expressions specified in the formula. For example, if the formula references a column of type money and a column of type int, the computed column will be of type money because that data type has the higher precedence. For more information, see Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL).

Specifically, in your case, the expression used to compute the column returns an nvarchar(4) - so that's the data type you should be using for the columns referencing it:
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RequestList]
(   
  [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,    
  [RequestID]  AS  ('R'+right('000'+CONVERT([nvarchar](10),[Id]),(3))) PERSISTED NOT NULL,
  [Date] date,  
  CustomerID nvarchar(50) foreign key references CustomerList(CustomerID),    
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RequestID] ASC),
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ServiceList]
(   
  ServiceID nvarchar(50) primary key, 
  ServiceType nvarchar(50),   
  Quantity int,   
  UnitPrice decimal(10,2),    
  TotalPrice decimal(10,2),   
  [RequestID] nvarchar(4) foreign key references RequestList([RequestID]) NULL
)



You can see the data types of the columns in dbo.RequestList by using sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set:
select *
  from sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set( N'select * from dbo.RequestList;', NULL, 0 );

The system_type_name returned for ResultID is nvarchar(4).
Another handy tool for exploring data type issues is SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY. It can be used on columns, expressions, ...:
select top 1 -- Yeah, no   ORDER BY .
  sql_variant_property( RequestID, 'BaseType' ) as BaseType,
  sql_variant_property( RequestID, 'MaxLength' ) as MaxLength
  from dbo.RequestList;

